# How to bind a folder of my hard disk on my webpage with datalist?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to show my drive all `jpg` file on my webpage

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(MapPath("D:\pstRZ"));
        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
        ArrayList listItems = new ArrayList();

        foreach (FileInfo info in files)
        {
            listItems.Add(info);
        }

        dtlist.DataSource = listItems;
        dtlist.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: what item exist in `pstRZ` ? jpeg images ? Those images to Webpage datalist ?

Comment: yes all are jpeg images

Comment: this code is to bind the folder exist with in the project but its not working when i have to bind data from drives

Comment: can you show me some item of your `listItems` ?

Comment: listItem is empty i and it arraylist in which i want to bind my drives images

Comment: You add `FileInfo info` to that `listItems` using `foreach` loop , isn't it ? I mean after adding fileInfo to your ListItems , what items have added to `listItems` ?

Comment: Path of Images but this code only works if i have a folder in my project but i want to access data from HDD

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store you images outside the web application folder, you need to have any way to provide the images to user, one of the solution is to use httphandler.

Here is your layout:

```
<asp:DataList runat="server" ID="dtlist">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <img src="GetImage.ashx?fileName=<%#Eval("Name")%>" alt="Image"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

It's you code:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    var dir = new DirectoryInfo("D:\\Images\\");
    var files = dir.GetFiles("*.png");
    var listItems = new ArrayList();

    foreach (FileInfo info in files)
    {
        listItems.Add(info);
    }

    dtlist.DataSource = listItems;
    dtlist.DataBind();
}
```

Here is the http handler GetImage.ashx:

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var root = "D:\\Images";

        var fileName = context.Request.Params["fileName"];
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName)) RenderInvalidRequestMessage(context);

        var fullFilePath = root + "\\" + fileName;
        //var dir = (new FileInfo(fullFilePath)).Directory;
        //if (dir == null || dir.FullName != root) RenderInvalidRequestMessage(context);

        if (!File.Exists(fullFilePath)) RenderInvalidRequestMessage(context);

        //TODO: Add validation and any security check.

        context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";            
        context.Response.WriteFile(fullFilePath);
    }

    private void RenderInvalidRequestMessage(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("File not found.");
        context.Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: from where the fileName will get Value whenever i load's page it's empty the code will redirect to renderinvelidrequest(....);

Comment: You page will render the code like 

     <table id="dtlist" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
 <tr>
  <td>
            <img src="GetImage.ashx?fileName=1.PNG" alt="Image"/>
        </td>
 </tr><tr>
  <td>
            <img src="GetImage.ashx?fileName=2.PNG" alt="Image"/>
        </td>
 </tr><tr>

And then browser will call your web application for each image with http://.../GetImage.ashx?fileName=1.PNG And this HTTP GET request will provide the filename via get-parameter.