# Image not displayed read from the system hard disk

Tags: asp.net, image

Image not displayed read from the system hard disk.

In my application I want to read the stored images in a folder called attachments. To run the application the user has to create a folder called attachments in his c drive.
The path of the files stored is below. *C:\Attachments\test.jpg*.
I want to read the images dynamically which is stored in this folder. I am able to get the name of the file from the database. The image will not be displayed in the image control.

I tried below ways:

```
ImageID. ImageURL= “C:\Attachments\test.jpg”

var url = Server.MapPath("~/Attachments / test.jpg");
  ImageID.ImageUrl = url;

ImageID.ImageUrl = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Attachments ") + "/test.jpg"
```

What is the exact way to display the image in image control  when the image is stored in the system disk  and the folder is not in web application path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> To run the application the user has to create a folder called attachments in his c drive.

This statement is somewhat ambiguous, but hopefully it means that **the user installing your application** must create a C:\Attachments folder *on the same machine as your Web application*. If that's the case, then the simplest solution is to open IIS Manager, right-click your application folder and add a virtual directory with the following settings:

- **Alias:** Attachments
- **Physical path:** C:\Attachments

The virtual directory will look like this:

[image: screenshot of IIS]

Then, in your .aspx page, just set the `ImageURL` property of your `Image` control to an app-relative URL:

```
this.ImageID.ImageUrl = "~/Attachments/test.jpg";
```

(You don't need to resolve the URL yourself. The `Image` control will resolve the ~ to an appropriate URL relative to the current request, and IIS will map the absolute URL sent by the browser to the C:\Attachments folder.)

---

However, if instead you meant to say that **every visitor to your site** must create a C:\Attachments folder *on his or her own machine*, then you should re-evaluate what you're trying to do: Browser security settings do not allow Web pages to access resources stored locally on client machines.

Answer (score 3):

You need to be clear with "web path", "system hard disk" or "his C drive".

In terms of web development, a disk which is attached to a client computer is a *client*, a disk which is attached to the web server is a *server*.

If all above is related to the *client* then there is only one case when it is possible - both, client and server are on a same machine and web application is added as a trusted site in IE. In this case you could see C:\Attachments\test.jpg as a part of a page. Other browsers might not support this. In all other cases it is not possible and also perhaps makes no sense.

If you want to do that on a *server* and you need to have that folder outside of the web application then you could have a ashx-handler which you will need to call from your image

ImageID.ImageURL="handler.ashx?image=test.jpg"

and from where you could read and output the image. Example: [How to bind a folder of my hard disk on my webpage with datalist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21673243/how-to-bind-a-folder-of-my-hard-disk-on-my-webpage-with-datalist)

Answer (score 2):

Try to modify your second example like this:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" />

Image2.ImageUrl = "~\images\test.png"
```

For me it works fine. Be also careful with the Whitespace in the paths!

**EDIT:**

Ok, you whant to use an Image from the Folder on the Client. You can't do this that way. Your codebehind is running on the Server, not on the Client. You can let the user upload a file on the server to use it. This will work that way:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadControl" runat="server" />    
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="UploadButton" Text="Upload" OnClick="UploadButton_Click" />

Dim filename As String = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName)
FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") & filename)
```

and then use the code above to Display the Image.
If it would work to Access to a Client the way you discribe above, any Webpage you visit could Access to all of your Files. Web protocols don't allow you to go steal a file of the client machine natively.

You will have to do one of these:

- FileUpload control, where the user selects
- An ActiveX installed on the client to send
- An exe running on the client to send

Comment: If a create a folder under web path this method works .... But i don want to add my images folder under web path

Comment: I think in that case you have to create a virtual Directory for the Folder first. Maybe this can help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwk103ab(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Make an `HttpHandler` for serving those images - that way you can serve images from any folder your web application has access to (including database or embedded resources in some library).

Assuming the generic handler will be named ImageHandler.ashx:

```
public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler {
  public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
    const string folder = @"c:\Attachments";
    string fileName = context.Request.QueryString["FileName"];
    var path = Path.Combine(folder, fileName);
    var mapping = new Dictionary<string, string> {
      { ".gif", "image/gif" },
      { ".jpg", "image/jpeg" },
      { ".jpeg", "image/jpeg" },
      { ".png", "image/png" },
      { ".bmp", "image/bmp" }
    };
    var info = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
    if (!info.FullName.StartsWith(folder, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
      // someone is using .. to hack our path - send him away
      context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
      context.Response.End();
      return;
    }

    if (!File.Exists(path)) {
      // file not found - 404
      context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
      context.Response.End();
      return;
    }

    // set some client caching - you can skip this if you don't want to
    context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
    context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddDays(3));

    var extension = Path.GetExtension(path).ToLowerInvariant();
    string contentType;
    if (!mapping.TryGetValue(extension, out contentType)) {
      contentType = "application/octet-stream";
    }
    context.Response.ContentType = contentType;
    context.Response.WriteFile(path);
  }

  public bool IsReusable {
    get { return false; }
  }
}
```

Now you can request images like

```
<asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" 
  ImageUrl="~/ImageHandlers.ashx?FileName=test.png" />
```

Aslo if you want to cache images also on server-side (and if you're using IIS7) you can setup entry in web config like:

```
<location path="ImageHandler.ashx">
  <system.webServer>
    <caching>
      <profiles>
        <add extension=".ashx" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" duration="00:00:10" varyByQueryString="FileName" />
      </profiles>
    </caching>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Answer (score 1):

You *have to* create a folder within the web application.

The browser just can't access files from arbitrary places on your hard disk. It can only access files which are served by your web server. That implies that the files must be within your web application.